# Solr7 using old schema.xml

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

We setup external Zookeper with 3 nodes and 3 Solr 7 instances.

I am trying to use `schema.xml` file from my old project created using Solr 4.

I follow bellow steps :

1. Rename the `managed-schema` file to `schema.xml`.
2. Modify `solrconfig.xml` to replace the `schemaFactory` class.

   a. Remove any `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory` definition if it exists.

   b. Add a `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory`

**uploaded configuration using upconfig**

```
sudo ./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /home/pc2/Desktop/solrconfig/conf-readData -confname readData -zkhost 192.168.1.120:2181,192.168.1.100:2181,192.168.1.105:2181

sudo ./zkcli.sh -cmd linkconfig -collection readData -confname readData -zkhost 192.168.1.120:2181,192.168.1.100:2181,192.168.1.105:2181

curl 'http://192.168.1.85:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=readData&numShards=3&replicationFactor=3&maxShardsPerNode=3'
```

When I check schema for `readData` from Solr admin, it is not showing fields that I mentioned in `schema.xml`.

Fields created were `_root_`, `_text_`, `_version_` and many more dynamic fields.

What I am missing?

- Solr version: 7.3.0
- Zookeper version: 3.4.12

Comment: Perhaps create the collection first and then link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems in what you do:

1. The `collection.configName` parameter is missing when you create the collection.
2. You must first create the collection and than link the configuration.

`linkconfig` is useful when you want change the current configuration with a new one, but you must specify the `collection.configName` parameter while creating a new collection or, on the other hand, the `_default` collection config is used.

This also explains why you see only `_root_`, `version`, `_text_`, etc. Those are the default fields configured in the `_default` collection configuration.

I suggest to create the collection in the following way:

```
curl "http://192.168.1.85:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=readData&collection.configName=readData&numShards=3&replicationFactor=3&maxShardsPerNode=3"
```

Or use the Solr admin console.